# Remove Downed Exchange Server from First Administrative Group

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003

I had a server die. It is gone forever.

It is still listed in the servers folder of the first administrative group in the Exchange System Manager.

When I click "all tasks > Remove Server" I get the following error:

```
The Server "SERVERNAME" cannot be removed because:
-One or more users currently use a mailbox on this server. 
These users must be moved to a mailbox store on a different server 
or be mail disabled before uninstalling this server.
Facility: Exchange System Manager
ID no: c103f492
Exchange System Manager
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

I cannot access the mailbox stores anymore and I do not care about the lost mailboxes. We deleted the inactive and old users as well. So I am stumped on this one. I just need to remove the old machine.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open AD and do a search for all users who have Exchange Home Server attribute set to the dead Exchange Server.  Remove Exchange mailbox association if you find any users using the old server.

Answer (score 0):

Knowledge Base article [833396](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833396) explains how to manually remove Exchange 2003.  Just keep in mind that you are obviously skipping the steps related to the server itself and just handling active directory.

One thing this article does not touch on is updating your connectors which may have been homed on that server and changing your public folder replication.

I would also follow [the advice](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Removing-First-Exchange-2003-Server-Part1.html) in this article to update public folders, connectors and other services and put them on your new Exchange server.

Comment: Doug,
Thank you for the reply.
KB833396 assumes the Exchange Server is still up and running. As well the manual process requires you to remove the users exchange mailboxes through AD. Unfortunately those users were deleted....

I have moved all the roles and public folders to the new server before the old one went offline. We just left the inactive users mailboxes.

The only remaining thing to remove is the server in the First Administrative Group in the Exchange System Manager. When I try to do so I get the error I wrote in the original post.

Thanks for the help!